# Notification hub registrations getting deleted

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

We are using notification hub to send notification to android devices.

Although things are working okay, I realized something. Registrations appear to get cleared up (some of them) after some time.

They may be invalid registrations, but it definitely looks like, azure does something behind the scenes to remove those.

Is there anything to suggest, azure deletes invalid registrations time to time? or is it something I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Notification Hubs Registration Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx) mentioned about **What is a Device Registration**:

> **It is important to note that registrations are transient**. Similar to the PNS handles that they contain, registrations expire. **You can set the time to live for a registration on the Notification Hub, up to a maximum of 90 days**. **This limit means that they must be periodically refreshed**, and also that they should not be the only store for important information. This automatic expiration also simplifies cleanup when your mobile application is uninstalled.

Also, from Push notifications with Azure Notification Hubs: Frequently asked questions.

> Notification Hubs cleans the registrations as it receives PNS feedback about expired or invalid registrations.